# Find Delete row in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i want to find and delete row like there are link in my database example 
google dot com , google dot com/gmail , facebook dot com etc what i want to do is find all links of https://google.com and delete the row 
Here is my code to delete row it will delete only the given row.

```
DELETE FROM community_links
WHERE link='google dot com';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Like to compare and the sentence will be delete all matches, for example:

```
DELETE FROM community_links
WHERE link like '%google%';
```

this match with every row that have the word google in the column link in any position.

Comment: Thanks for the help if you like my answer please vote me up

Answer (score 0):

I have find the answer if some one want to use the code this is working code thanks for support

```
DELETE FROM community_links
WHERE link like 'https://fmovies.se%';
```